# Are vampires and werewolves on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Seems there are already some questions about [vampires](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampires) and [werewolves](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolves)? However they have been closed.

So I wonder, are these creatures are part of the mythology and can be on-topic here?

Comment: Vampires and Werewolves are very widespread concepts in European folklore, therefore I don't think it would make sense to exclude them if we decide that folklore is on-topic (which seems to be the case). That said, I will mercilessly downvote any and all Twilight questions that may appear on the site. ;)